# AWK not printing output file separator OFS

Tags: bash, awk

Input

```
15.01.2018;Payment sent;;500.00;;
20.12.2017;Payment received;10.40;;;
```

Expected output

```
15.01.2018;Payment sent;-500.00
20.12.2017;Payment received;10.40
```

Current output

```
15.01.2018Payment sent-500.00
20.12.2017Payment received10.40
```

Does one see the problem in my command?

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=";";FS=";"} {print match($4, /[^ ]/) ? $1$2$3"-"$4 : $1$2$3}' < in.csv > out.csv
```

Thank you

Comment: I'm not able to add a simple 'Hi' when editing...so I do it here: Hi

Comment: What is the condition(s) to get your expected output? Since first line is having a `-` and 2nd is not? Please be more specific in same.

Comment: You can use `OFS`: `print match ... ? $1 OFS $2 ...`.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I've added the input in order to clarify: If $4 contains a value, add a hyphen to $4

Comment: Thank you @PesaThe. Could you elaborate please? I don't understand

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't understand why you're surprised that when you print `$1$2$3` there's no OFS between them but I also don't understand why you were trying to use the logic in your script at all instead of just:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {print $1, $2, ($3=="" ? "-"$4 : $3)}' file
15.01.2018;Payment sent;-500.00
20.12.2017;Payment received;10.40
```

Comment: What if both `$3` and `$4` are present?

Comment: Based on the $2 text values (one is money "sent" while the other is money "received") I don't see how they could be and the OP didn't show that in the sample input/output. Looks to me like the OP is just trying to create a single column she can then sum at the bottom for a total.

Comment: True true, sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk -F";" '$4~/[0-9]/{$4="-"$4}{gsub(/;+/,";");sub(/;$/,"")}  1' OFS=";"  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
15.01.2018;Payment sent;-500.00
20.12.2017;Payment received;10.40
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code too now.

```
awk -F";" '         ##Setting field separator as semi colon here.
$4~/[0-9]/{         ##Checking condition here if 4th field is having digit in it, if yes then do following:
  $4="-"$4          ##Adding a dash(-) before 4th field value here.
}
{
  gsub(/;+/,";");   ##By Globally substitution method Removing multiple semi colons occurrences with single semi colon here, as per OP shown output.
  sub(/;$/,"")      ##By using normal substitution method replacing semi colon which comes at last of line with NULL here.
}
1                   ##awk works on method of condition{action}, so here I am making condition TRUE and NOT mentioning any action so default print will happen.
' OFS=";" Input_file##Setting OFS(Output field separator) as semi colon here and mentioning Input_file name here too.
```

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers is actually responsive to the OP's question.  The question was "Why isn't the OFS appearing in the output?"  The answer is quite simple, and one person made a snarky comment in the right direction but nobody actually answered.

Here's the answer:  In the ... print $1$2$3... part, there are no spaces between $1, $2, and $3, so you've asked awk to just put those fields right next to each other with no space or field separator.  If you had ... print $1,$2,$3.. then you'd have the result you are looking for.

And yes I know this is an old dead question

Comment: Shouldn't even be using `;` as `FS / OFS` at all for this task

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/sent;;/,"sent;-")sub(/;;+/,"")}1' file

15.01.2018;Payment sent;-500.00
20.12.2017;Payment received;10.40
```

The first sub changes semicolon to dash and the second removes semicolons after last zero.

Comment: Explanations of this awk command set would make this answer a perfect answer as asker/reader may not feel confortable with awk. [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely no point in using `";"` as either `FS` or `OFS`

> ```
> {m,g}awk 'sub(";*$",_,$!(NF=NF))' FS='sent;+' OFS='sent;-'
> ```

> ```
> {m,g}awk NF=NF RS=';*\r?\n' FS='sent;+' OFS='sent;-'
> ```

```
15.01.2018;Payment sent;-500.00
20.12.2017;Payment received;10.40
```